# Getting server url with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to get my server's current origin. For example, if I have a node server on `http://localhost:3000` then I should get `http://localhost:3000` as the origin. We do have `location.origin` for browser javascript to get the origin url. But is there a way to get the server's origin?

Comment: Are you trying to access the server url from server-side code? Like request handler for example?

Comment: @ne1410s Yes, I need to access server url from server.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with express js :

```
req.hostname
```